# Add the first element to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue atomically

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, lock-free

I want to use a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) in an atomic [lock-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) manner:

Several concurrent threads push events into the queue and some other thread will process them. The queue is not bound and I don't want any thread to wait or get locked. The reading part however may notice that the queue got empty. In a lock free implementation the reading thread must not block but will just end its task and proceeds executing other tasks (i.e. as an ExecutorService). Thus the writer pushing the first new event into an empty queue must become aware about it and should restart the reader (i.e. by submitting a new Runnable to the ExecutorService) to process the queue. Any further threads submitting a second or third event won't care about, as they may assume some reader was already prepared/submitted.

Unfortunately the [add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html#add%28E%29) method of ConcurrentLinkedQueue always returns true. Asking the queue if isEmpty() before or after adding the event won't help, as it is not atomic. 
Should I use some additional AtomicInteger for monitoring the queue size() or is there some smarter solution for that?

Dieter.

Comment: Extend `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, override the `add()` method, have it fire processor-thread if one is needed. You may have a race condition where two or more processor-threads are fired, but they can handle that with a synchronized lock - the only blocking that will occur is on a thread that will die soon anyway, no legitimate worker is blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using of `AtomicInteger` for resolving submit contention is more efficient than locks or `synchronized` block.

- Here is [an example how it can be implemented with Java](https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/control/parallel/Actor.java).
- Also there is [more efficient structure for multi-producer / single-writer queue](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/actors/MPSCQueue.scala) than ConcurrentLinkedQueue.
- [Example of using it for actor implementations](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/actors/ThreadBasedActor.scala).
- [Another example](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/actors/Actor2.scala).

Comment: Last night I ran single-threaded benchmarks (using Google Caliper) for MPSCQueue, AoMP's [LockFreeQueue](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/art-of-multiprocessor-programming/5QKzw8-SotE), and CLQ. I generally saw CLQ at 35ns and the others at 500-600ns and a high CPU spike (likely due to bus contention). My custom lock-free ring buffer performs best, but I haven't figured out how to handle overflows to a CQL safely yet.

Comment: I rewrote the [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/3181092) since I had discarded it locally. Similar results.

Comment: I played around and haven't figured out why benchmark results differ so greatly. Your benchmarks don't perform any JVM warm-up or try to evaluate until the performance hits a steady state, so there's a chance that the earlier runs are unfairly penalized.

On mine my best guess is that Caliper is running multiple tests concurrently and the TAS style cas operations are causing a bus storm and CPU spikes (not leveraging mesi cache coherence for L1 spins). Of course it could just be a busted benchmark. It would be great if you could port mine into your environment.

Comment: I wouldn't believe benchmarking frameworks so blindly...
Here is simple test and output that prove better performance of MPSCQueue: https://gist.github.com/3181092#gistcomment-380023

Comment: Thanks Andriy. I'll give it a shot on CLHM and run it through my other (non-Caliper) benchmarks. I'll probably talk with my friends writing Caliper and see if they have any ideas. Generally its been good on single-threaded tests, but I have a few ideas for where it may have some buggy assumptions.

Comment: Thank you too, Ben! Please share your ideas... they will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Oh, my ideas are for why Caliper may be misbehaving. For MPSCQueue, I'm curious if a TTAS style spin may offer better performance under contention. You may want to try Shavit's LockFreeQueue example in your benchmarks as well and see how it performs.

Comment: It occurred to me how to have my lock-free MPSC ring buffer safely overflow to your MPSC linked queue. This gives characteristics I want in CLHM's buffers: array-based behavior in the common case, O(1) size, and unbounded. I'll write it up this weekend and send you the git repo.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand why you wouldn't just use an `ExecutorService` directly for this.  It uses a `BlockingQueue` internally and takes care of all of the signaling itself.

```
// open ended thread pool
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
for (Job job : jobsToDo) {
    threadPool.submit(new MyJobProcessor(job));
}
```

Unless you have good reasons, I would not rewrite the same logic yourself.

If you are trying to make use of dormant threads somehow, I would strongly recommend not bothering.  Threads are relatively cheap so assigning a thread to process your queued tasks is fine.  Re-using threads is unnecessary and seems like premature optimization to me.

Comment: It depends on requirements, if high throughput or low latency is required than actor (lightweight thread, low memory footprint) or disruptor (OS thread, preallocated buffer) implementations can be used: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/LMAX

Comment: Uh sure @Andriy but unless a profiler tells you that the `ExecutorService` is your bottleneck, there is no point in making things more complicated.

Comment: I already do that. I mentioned a thread consuming the queue, but indeed it ts a Runnable task of my underlying ExecutorService.

Comment: Until the submitted processor is ready to start processing the events some more events may have been enqueued but I don't want to submit additional processors. Finally, after all events are processed the processor task must not simply wait (as with a blocking queue) since it would block the current thread of my ExecutorService. Instead it MUST terminate (the Runnable task, not the thread) and has to be restarted if further events come in.<br/>Meanwhile I think some AtomicInteger will do the job.