# How to run a Listener in a different thread or do its calculation in a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, guava

I'm trying to build a cache with Google Guava and want to do some calculation on the expired objects. A removalListener notifies me, if some object was removed.

How can I run the removalListener in a different thread than the main application or pass the expired object (in the simple example below, that would be the Integer 3) to a different thread that handles the calculation?

Edit: As the calculation is rather short, but happens often, I would rather not create a new thread each time (would be thousands of threads), but have one (or maybe two) who calculate all objects.

Simple example:

```
Cache<String, Integer> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(100)
        .expireAfterAccess(100, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
        .removalListener(new RemovalListener<String, Integer>() {
            public void onRemoval(final RemovalNotification notification) {
                if (notification.getCause() == RemovalCause.EXPIRED) {
                    System.out.println("removed " + notification.getValue());
                    // do calculation=> this should be in another thread
                }
            }
        })
        .build();
 cache.put("test1", 3);
 cache.cleanUp();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To run your listener in an executor, wrap it with [RemovalListeners.asynchronous](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/RemovalListeners.html#asynchronous%28com.google.common.cache.RemovalListener,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor%29).

.removalListener(**asynchronous**(new RemovalListener() { ... }, executor))

Comment: +1 nice one. very elegant and belongs to the library in question. "Just add water" (or an executor service)

Comment: +1. Didn't know about this one. It eliminates the boilerplate code of creating Runnable instances. If only some removals must be done in a separate thread (and not just the ones caused by expiration), it doesn't work, though.

Comment: :o How do I know the executor to pass to the constructor? I am trying something like: 
  CacheBuilder.newBuilder().removalListener(new RemovalListener() { ...

Answer (score 7):

Create an ExecutorService using one of the [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) factory methods, and submit a new Runnable to this executor each time you need to:

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

...

public void onRemoval(final RemovalNotification notification) {
    if (notification.getCause() == RemovalCause.EXPIRED) {
        System.out.println("removed " + notification.getValue());
        submitCalculation(notification.getValue());
    }
}

private void submitCalculation(final Integer value) {
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // call your calculation here
        }
    };
    executor.submit(task);
}
```

Comment: Hi JB,
I know you can pass arguments to new threads. But how about having just one or two who do all the work? If I create one anew each time, I would soon have thousands of them.

Comment: That's precisely what the above is doing. It uses a single background thread (hence the name `newSingleThreadExecutor()`) to execute all submitted tasks. Don't confuse threads and Runnables. A Runnable is just a piece of executable code. A thread can execute several such pieces of code.

Comment: @JBNizet so this will not create thread everytime time a task is submitted, only one thread will be there ?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new class, and implement the `java.utils.Runnable` interface like so;

```
public class MyWorkerThread implements Runnable {

    public MyWorkerThread(/*params*/) {
        //set your instance variables here
        //then start the thread
        (new Thread(this)).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        //do useful things
    }
}
```

When you create a new `MyWorkerThread` by calling the constructor, execution is returned to the calling code as soon as the constructor is finished, and a separate thread is started that runs the code inside the `run()` method.

If you might want to create `MyWorkerThread` objects without immediately starting them off, you can remove the `Thread.start()` code from the constructor, and call the thread manually from the instance later like so;

```
MyWorkerThread t = new MyWorkerThread();
//later
(new Thread(t)).start();
```

Or if you want to keep a reference to the `Thread` object so you can do groovy things like **interrupt** and **join**, do it like so;

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(t);
myThread.start();
//some other time
myThread.interrupt();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply create intermediate queue for expired entities (expiration listener will just add expired object to this queue) - say some sort of blocking in-memory queue - ArrayBlockingQueue, LinkedBlockingDeque.

Then you can setup thread-pool and handlers(with configurable size) that will consume objects using poll() **method**.

For high-performance queue - i can advice more advanced non-blocking queue implementation if needed. also you can read more about high-performance non-blocking queues here [Add the first element to a ConcurrentLinkedQueue atomically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654794/add-the-first-element-to-a-concurrentlinkedqueue-atomically/11661586#11661586)

Comment: Great idea. If you could advice some non-blocking queues, that would be helpful. Although I suspect I have to do a lot more research to understand the concepts of the implementation in actor implementations

Comment: for non-blocking queue in general - please take a look here https://raw.github.com/gist/3181092/14e7d4f88da26aba7ef46092f464280a74abf715/LockFreeQueue.java for details.

Answer (score 1):

Use an executor service to dispatch your task to a different thread. 
ExecutorService have an internal blocking queue that is used for safe publishing of references between the producer and the consumer threads. The factory class [Executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) can be used to create different `ExecutorService` with different thread management strategies.

```
private ExecutorService cleanupExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CLEANUP_THREADPOOL_SIZE); 
...
public void onRemoval(final RemovalNotification notification) {
    if (notification.getCause() == RemovalCause.EXPIRED) {
        System.out.println("removed " + notification.getValue());
        doAsyncCalculation(notification.getValue());
    }
}

private void doAsyncCalculation(final Object obj) {
    cleanupExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            expensiveOperation(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

In `doAsyncCalculation` you are creating new tasks to be run but not new threads. The executor service takes care of dispatching the task to the threads in the executorService's associated thread pool.